# gulp_jspm DeprecationWarning

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp, systemjs, jspm

When I use gulp_jspm I get this DeprecationWarning is there something else I should use to create my bundle files? When I used gulp-jspm-build I have to add some node files that I never had to do before.

> Should I use `gulp-jspm-build'`?

**Current versions:**

node: v6.9.5
ts: 2.7.2

```
.pipe(gulp_jspm({
    selfExecutingBundle: true
}),true)
```

(node:25936) [DEP0097] DeprecationWarning: Using a domain property in MakeCallback is deprecated. Use the async_context variant of MakeCallback or the AsyncResource class instead. (Triggered by calling processImmediate on process.)
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the author of `gulp-jspm`, it has not been updated or maintained since 2017.

https://github.com/brillout/gulp-jspm/issues/45

Comment: Is there something I should use to replace it with?

Comment: @Jefferson I am not really familiar with JSPM but it looks like they recommend using Chomp. https://chompbuild.com/